# How to make jqPlot work with the bar chart example

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot

I am trying to run an example from `jqPlot`. I adapted their code to my page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Tests</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>Testing a chart 2</div>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="jqplot.barRenderer.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jqplot.categoryAxisRenderer.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jqplot.pointLabels.min.js"></script>

        <script language=javascript type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    var s1 = [200, 600, 700, 1000];
                    var s2 = [460, -210, 690, 820];
                    var s3 = [-260, -440, 320, 200];
                    // Can specify a custom tick Array.
                    // Ticks should match up one for each y value (category) in the series.
                    var ticks = ['May', 'June', 'July', 'August'];

                    var plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [s1, s2, s3], {
                        // The "seriesDefaults" option is an options object that will
                        // be applied to all series in the chart.
                        seriesDefaults: {
                            renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer,
                            rendererOptions: {fillToZero: true}
                        },
                        // Custom labels for the series are specified with the "label"
                        // option on the series option.  Here a series option object
                        // is specified for each series.
                        series: [
                            {label: 'Hotel'},
                            {label: 'Event Regristration'},
                            {label: 'Airfare'}
                        ],
                        // Show the legend and put it outside the grid, but inside the
                        // plot container, shrinking the grid to accomodate the legend.
                        // A value of "outside" would not shrink the grid and allow
                        // the legend to overflow the container.
                        legend: {
                            show: true,
                            placement: 'outsideGrid'
                        },
                        axes: {
                            // Use a category axis on the x axis and use our custom ticks.
                            xaxis: {
                                renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                                ticks: ticks
                            },
                            // Pad the y axis just a little so bars can get close to, but
                            // not touch, the grid boundaries.  1.2 is the default padding.
                            yaxis: {
                                pad: 1.05,
                                tickOptions: {formatString: '$%d'}
                            }
                        }
                    });
                });
        </script>

        <div id="chart1" style="height:400px;width:300px; "></div>

        <br><a href="/Test/index.html">Home</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Note that I created the `div` with the chart name *`chart1`*, then plugins were added accordingly.

Comment: Just a little FYI: `language=javascript` was never really required, and `type="text/javascript"` hasn't been required for a number of years (certainly not when using `<!DOCTYPE html>`), so you can just use `<script>` :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the main "jqplot" javascript file and not only the plugin files :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.jqplot.js"></script>
```

Please see working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/AnthonyLeGovic/QeUv6/)

**PS** : about your Chart2.html file (in your archive)

1. You have to load files in a precise order : First jquery, then jqplot, and finally jqlot plugins (without any particular order between them).
2. You have mispelled jqplot file : jquery.jqplot.min.js (don't forget the 'q' letter)
3. You don't need to load both jquery.jqplot.min.js and jquery.jqplot.js as it is the same content (the difference is in the minification).
4. Don't forget to load jqplot CSS if you want your graph to be well-displayed.

Thus the correct javascript and css inclusion is :

```
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.jqplot.min.js"></script>
<script src="jqplot.barRenderer.min.js"></script>
<script src="jqplot.categoryAxisRenderer.min.js"></script>
<script src="jqplot.pointLabels.min.js"></script>
<link href="jquery.jqplot.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Comment: This is already in the code, and it is not working. Do you see anything else? Thanks

Comment: I have edited my post. You need to add the main jqplot javascript file (jquery.jqplot.js) as the other files are "only" plugins

Comment: Ohh, thanks I will try it as soon as I get home and let you know the result!

Comment: It did not work. I added my NB project in this link if you can help me out: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/30676916/Test.zip

Comment: I have worked on your Chart2.html file, see the edited post above

Comment: I did not know about the correct order! Awesome thank you a lot. I am trying to positive your answer but I don't have enough "credits" for that. Thanks!

Comment: You can maybe accept it if your problems are solved. Anyway you're welcome!